# drupal views facebook like button

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, facebook-like

I tried to add facebook like button to my veiws, which lists a particular node-type. I used views custom field module to add the iframe code.

The problem is when I click like..

it shows **Nikhil liked http://example.com/node/44**

instead it should have shown **Nikhil liked *node title* on example.com**.

Where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oK , well I was able to achieve the above feature by following methods:

1. Created a cck field url-alias under a content type for which views is being created.
2. Using views-custom-field module, I put in the facebook iframe code.
3. in my views I included the url-alias field in hidden form and used it to form the url in the like code.
4. I also used the fb-social module and after that all my likes button were working as expected.

Comment: Can you you explain #1 further?  I have tried this before but views generates the same like button instance, over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Use Open Graph tags:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Comment: open graph tags are only useful when you have one facebook like on a page.
I might have around 50-100 on one page.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out how I did it here: http://www.jerryjr.com/adding-facebook-like-button-your-drupal-site