# Drupal 6 view page Like button for each node

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I currently have a view page displaying fields containing images or videos from each node.  I also am utilizing colorbox to see each image and video.

My Goal:
Add a like button to each node on the view.
The post on facebooks wall needs to link back to the view page which  (This is where it start to get complex) will dynamically open the colorbox (last on my priority list for now)

I have used http://drupal.org/project/fb_social which works wonderfully with views but that og:url is going back to http://localhost:8888/node/100.  I can continue down this route but I need finer grain control of that url.

I also discovered this post: [drupal views facebook like button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501820/drupal-views-facebook-like-button) 
which is a little vague.  If I simply add the like button code to a view customfield, all views will do is duplicated the button instance over and over.  If I click like once on node/4 then all other nodes on the page are also liked...

I really like the Facebook social plugins integration module but out of the box, it points to the full node page.  Any advice on how to customize that url?  I even thought about using a Path Redirect module but i don't think its a viable solution.

Setup:
Drupal 6.22
Views 6.x-3.0-rc3
fb social plugins 6.x-1.0-beta9

Comment: Which Drupal and fb_social versions do you use?

Comment: @ HenrikOpel - Let me know if i can provide anything else. I would love to know if this was possible through fb-social mod

Comment: I've last used fb_social 6.x-1.0-beta4, which did not have the views integration yet, so I need to take a look into the new version first before making recommendations that could well be obsolete. From what I can see so far, you might be able to manipulate the URL in question by extending the `fb_social_like_handler_field_like` class, overriding the `render()` method within that to change the used URL (you could test if this works by adjusting the method directly before messing around with a class extension).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is going to be by overriding the template for your specific view and you'll also avoid the added overhead of another module load. You want to add the Facebook like js code into the top of your page somewhere (ex. in the view header) (from: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=132294920190866";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And then in the specific row template for each of your rows, add the output code

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://localhost:8888/myurl" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

For theming the row template, check out the views 2 theming guide:

http://drupal.org/node/352970

or try the semantic views module if you expect to be doing more theming or don't want to mess with template files:

http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews

Comment: Thanks ill try this, but wouldn't your answer result in multiple instances of the same like button displaying multiple times?

Comment: Well thats where the theming would come in -- in place of the url in the above div, you would add the field variable you want to target.

Comment: I might be doing this wrong. I have the row template: views-view-fields--media-gallery.tpl.php and the like button data-href is pointing to [path] from a views field i am hiding.  This still translates to the same button being repeated multiple times.

Comment: Also, the like button is putting http://%5Bpath%5D/ which is from [path]. I also tried http://[path]. this appears as the og:url

Comment: @arkjoseph: There might be an easier way, so once more - which Drupal and fb_social versions do you use?

Comment: See updated question. Thanks! Sorry, didn't notice your comment up top.